# Regression equation given a joint distribution

Tags: regression, probability, self-study

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint probability density function

$f(x,y)$ = $   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 &  -y\leq x\leq y , & 0 < y <1\\
      0 & elsewhere \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

Find the regression equation of $Y$ on $X$ and that of $X$ on $Y$.

I have read about linear regression but I have never encountered something like this. I have no idea what the problem is asking. I am preparing for an exam and this was one of sample question. An idea or elaboration of the problem is all I need.

Comment: Are you able to draw the domain of $x$ and $y$ on a graph? I suppose what it means by a regression equation is something like $E(Y|x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$. So find $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ that describes $E(Y|x)$.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read the tag wiki.

Comment: Regression of $Y$ on $X$ is given by the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X)$ (this may or may not be linear in $X$). Does that sound familiar? This is your starting point.

Comment: If you _sketch_ the region on which $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed, then you _might_ be able to conclude that for any fixed value $x \in (-1,1)$, the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $U(|x|,1)$ and so $E[Y \mid X] $ is trivial to compute by inspection.  Note that the _linear_ regression of $Y$ on $X$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

E[Y|X] is the regression line resulting from regressing Y on X.
E[X|Y] is the regression line resulting from regressing Y on X.

Jsst find the conditional pdf of X|Y and then the expectation.